# Usage of a non-final local variable within an inner class

Tags: java, class

[JLS 8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) gives us the rule about variables which are not declared in an inner class but used in the class.

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but
>   not declared in an inner class must either be declared final or be
>   effectively final (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs where the
>   use is attempted.

An example:

```
class A{
    void baz(){
        int i = 0;
        class Bar{ int j = i; }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/8QSDpn)**

Why was the code compiled? We used the non-final local variable in the inner class which was no declared in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable `i` defined inside method baz is effictively final because value of variable i is not modified elsewhere. If you change it

```
void baz(){
        int i = 0;
        i = 2;
        class Bar{ int j = i; }
    }
```

The code will fail to compile because variable `i` is no longer effictively final but if you just declare the variable i and the initialize it in another line, the code will compile because the variable is effictively final

```
  void baz(){
        int i;
        i = 2;
        class Bar{ int j = i; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`i` is effectively final, since it is never modified. As you yourself quoted the JLS, the inner class may use effectively final variables.

Answer (score 1):

Because `i` is effectively final as it is not changed in `baz`.